# Creating a string literal from a define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, string-literals

Lets say I have a define like so:

```
#define MY_FUNC_NAME my_func
```

I want to get a string literal for it, e.g. `"my_func"`.

I tried using the hash preprocessor operator like so:

```
#define str(s) #s
#define MY_FUNC_NAME_LITERAL str(MY_FUNC_NAME)
```

But this would yield `"MY_FUNC_NAME"` instead of `"my_func"`, as though it does not replace it before creating the literal.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Call indirectly. E.g `#define str(s) str_(s)` `#define str_(s) #s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) explains, you need two macros to do that

```
 #define xstr(s) str(s)
 #define str(s) #s
 #define foo 4
 str (foo)
      ==> "foo"
 xstr (foo)
      ==> xstr (4)
      ==> str (4)
      ==> "4"
```

Actual answer for this problem:

```
#define str_(s) #s
#define str(s) str_(s)
#define MY_FUNC_NAME_LITERAL str(MY_FUNC_NAME)
#define MY_FUNC_NAME my_func
```

Comment: I thought i read it carefully but I missed the second indirect call... Thanks.